# MediaRecorder static object becomes null in onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, static-variables

I have a BroadcastReceiver for receive call states and record calls.

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static MediaRecorder recorder;

    ...
}
```

The problem is when the call takes a long time, the `recorder object` becomes null.

I know android OS kills the application's process after a while and clears static variables from memory for freeing up the device's RAM.

It is clear that I can't use `Preferences` or `Database` for saving `recorder object`.

So how can I solve my problem?

Note: I have this problem just in `android 6`.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

I have a `Service` that starts `BroadcastReceiver class` and a method that registers the receiver:

```
public class TService extends Service {
     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

          ...

          br_call = new CallBroadcastReceiver();
          this.registerReceiver(br_call, filter);

          //****** THE SOLUTION IS HERE *******
          return START_STICKY;
     }
}
```

I replaced the `return START_NO_STICKY;` with `return START_STICKY;` so the `receiver's variables` sticks in the memory during the calls and then the `recorder object` never becomes `null`.